# PL/SQL How to add a WHERE clause in function of the value of a field in the same query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to do something like these

pseudocode:

```
SELECT a.OPERATION, b.NAME
FROM OPERATIONS a, NAMES b, IDENTIFIERS c
WHERE
if (a.OPERATION='upload') {
  b.ID=c.ID_UPLOAD
}else {
b.ID=c.ID_DOWNLOAD
}
```

I know that I can not add CASE statement in WHERE clause. Does somebody know how to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason you are choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Gordon: What does a Join have to do with this?

Comment: What is the relation of OPERATIONS  to any of the other 2 tables?

Comment: I think you're going to have to state your intent.  It's not clear by looking at the code you've posted what you intend to accomplish.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: it seems Adrian is trying to do some kind of "conditional" join in the WHERE clause. Although I don't understand how PL/SQL is supposed to come into play here

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression in the `ON` clause of the join:

```
SELECT o.OPERATION, n.NAME
FROM OPERATIONS o
INNER JOIN NAMES n ON n.? = o.?
INNER JOIN IDENTIFIERS i 
ON n.ID = CASE o.OPERATION WHEN 'upload' THEN i.ID_UPLOAD ELSE i.ID_DOWNLOAD END
```

Replace the `?` placeholders with the names of the columns that relate `OPERATIONS` to `NAMES`.

Comment: Will Oracle optimize this case expression as good as regular AND/OR logic?

Comment: @jarlh I can't tell. If the OP mentioned that there is a value like `'download'` in the column `OPERATION` (just like there is `'upload'`), I would write the `ON` clause like: `ON (o.OPERATION = 'upload' AND n.ID = i.ID_UPLOAD) OR (o.OPERATION = 'download' AND n.ID = i.ID_DOWNLOAD)`